# pagecreate is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile, cordova

Whenever I am trying to run, their is an error popping up that "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'changePage' of undefined`" . I think there is an error in the loginPage creation. Anyone please help with the following error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
    function deviceReady() {
        console.log("deviceReady");
        $(document).on("pagecreate", "#loginPage", function () {
            alert("pageinit run");
            $("#loginForm").on("submit", handleLogin);
            checkPreAuth();
        });
        $.mobile.changePage("#loginPage", {
            transition: "pop",
            reverse: false,
            changeHash: false
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happening

You are doing everything wrong.

First page events should NOT be called inside Cordova/Phonegap deviceReady() function, there's no point. Move it level above, this code does not care if device is ready or not, it will execute when you transition to page **#loginPage**. And that will usually be way way after Phonegap is in **deviceReady()** state.

Second thing, you CAN'T execute changePage function inside **deviceReady()** function. jQuery Mobile is not initialized correctly nor is page container available. Thus you can't change page if pages still don't event exist in the DOM.

Third thing, lets say hypothetical that page container is available during **deviceReady()** state (which is not true) this will still not work because at this point jQuery Mobile will try to initialize first page inside initial HTML file and you can't just stop it with another change page.

Basically your code should look similar to this:

```
function deviceReady() {
    console.log("deviceReady");
}

$(document).on("pageshow", "#someInitialPage", function () {
    $.mobile.changePage("#loginPage", {
        transition: "pop",
        reverse: false,
        changeHash: false
    });
});

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#loginPage", function () {
    alert("pageinit run");
    $("#loginForm").on("submit", handleLogin);
    checkPreAuth();
});
```

#### What have we learn

- Never mix Phonegap and jQuery Mobile code like this, they should always run separately unless there's a really good reason in mixing them
- Page events should always run separately
- You can't initiate **changePage** before first page is initialized (there's one way but I will show it to you only if you need it)
- **changePage** can only be initialized during some page event, or in any function which is initialized during some page event. Basically page container must exist before **pageChange** can occur.

#### If you really really need to run some code when Phonegap and jQuery Mobile is initialized then use this code:

```
var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();

document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);

function deviceReady() {
  deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
}

$(document).one("mobileinit", function () {
  jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
});

$.when(deviceReadyDeferred, jqmReadyDeferred).then(doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded);

function doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded() {
  // TBD
}
```

#### If you want to determine which initial page to load first use this code

This code can prevent initial page initialization and you can use it to load any other page:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforechange', function(e, data){ 
    var to = data.toPage;

    if (typeof to  === 'string') {
        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(to);
        to = u.hash || '#' + u.pathname.substring(1);

        if (to === '#second') {
            alert('Can not transition the page #second!');
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            // remove active status on a button, if transition was triggered with a button
            $.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active ui-shadow').css({'box-shadow':'0 0 0 #3388CC'});
        } 
    }
});
```

Read more about it [**here**](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-prevent-jquery-mobile-page-navigation/).

Comment: Hi @Raunak if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. If you have additional questions not directly asked in this question you should open another one.